# How to add background-color in LilyPond?

Tags: pdf, notation, lilypond

I'm searching for a way to add a background color to parts of a LilyPond generated musical score. Is there a way to achieve this within the syntax of LilyPond? My research so far has only shown ways to color noteheads by pitch.

[Here you can see, what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm8gH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, you'll need to add your own functions. Fortunately, someone already wrote them. There's an example on the LSR which shows how to use different kinds of backgrounds as annotations: https://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=1000

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).